# Why is my android application not able to read JSON on server?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm one step away from publishing my application to Android PlayStore.  However, I'm stuck on one problem and that is my Android application (written in Kotlin) is not able to read Json file on my server (dreamhost.com).  The URL for the JSON is at: https://apis.androidparadise.site/contacts/Contacts.json.

```
    data class ContactResponseItem(
       val comment: String?,
       @SerializedName("data")
       val dataList: List<Data?>,
       val database: String?,
       val name: String?,
       val type: String?,
       val version: String?
    )
```

My interface is:

```
        interface ContactApi {
           @GET("/contacts/Contacts.json")
           suspend fun getAllContacts() : Response<List<ContactResponseItem>>
           @POST("/contacts/new")
           suspend fun addContact(@Body contact:ContactResponseItem): 
           Response<ContactResponseItem>
        }
```

My repository is:

```
        interface ContactsRepository {
            suspend fun getAllContacts(): Resource<List<ContactResponseItem>>
            suspend fun addContact(contact: ContactResponseItem): 
        Resource<ContactResponseItem>
    }
```

My default repository is:

```
     class ContactsRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val api: ContactApi):
ContactsRepository {
override suspend fun getAllContacts(): Resource<List<ContactResponseItem>> {
    return try {
        val response = api.getAllContacts()
        val result = response.body()

        if (response.isSuccessful && result != null) {
           Resource.Success(result)

        }
        else {
            Resource.Error("Response was not successful")
        }

    }catch (e: Exception){
        Resource.Error (e.message ?: "Failed to retrieve contacts")
    }
}



override suspend fun addContact(contact: ContactResponseItem): Resource<ContactResponseItem> {

    return try {
        val response = api.addContact(contact)
        val result = response.body()

        Log.d("ContactsRepositoryImpl", response.isSuccessful.toString())
        Log.d("ContactRepositoryImpl", (result != null).toString())
        if (response.isSuccessful && result != null) {
             Resource.Success(result)
        }
        else {
            Resource.Error("Response was not successful")
        }

    }catch (e: Exception){
        Resource.Error (e.message ?: "Failed to retrieve contacts")
    }


}
```

One of my methods from my ViewModel:

```
       fun getContactEmails(): MutableList<String> {

    viewModelScope.launch(dispatchers!!.io) {
        when (val loadResponse = contactsRepo.getAllContacts()) {

            is Resource.Success ->{

                for(i in 0..loadResponse.data?.size!!){
                    if (loadResponse.data[i].name == "data") {
                        val dataLoad = loadResponse.data[i].dataList[0]
                        dataLoad?.let { emailList.add(it.email) }
                    }

                }


              _recipientload.value = RecipientLoadingEvent.Success("The first email found: ${emailList[0]}")

            }
            is Resource.Error<*> -> RecipientLoadingEvent.Failure("Couldn't load client's emails")
            else -> _recipientload.value =
                RecipientLoadingEvent.Failure(loadResponse.errorMsg.toString())
        }

    }
    return emailList
}
```

Finally one method from the main activity:

```
       contactsVM.recipientLoad.collect { event ->
            when (event) {
                is ContactsViewModel.RecipientLoadingEvent.Success -> {
                   Toast.makeText(this@CreateNewUserRegistration, contactsVM.getContactEmails()[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }

                is ContactsViewModel.RecipientLoadingEvent.Failure -> {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@CreateNewUserRegistration,
                         "Failed to retrieve email",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()

                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@CreateNewUserRegistration,
                        "Failed to send data to server",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()

                }


                else -> {}
            }
        }
```

For some reason, in the main activity the event variable in the when statement is returning ContactsViewModel.RecipientLoadingEvent.Error instead of ContactsViewModel.RecipientLoadingEvent.Success.  I'm only receiving the two Toasts that failed to retrieve the data.  I'm not receiving any error messages from my view model.  This only leads me to believe that reading/uploading of the JSON file is not done correctly.

Comment: Well the uploading is ok as your link delivers a fine file.

Comment: So much code. And what goes wrong? You first have to download the beast. Now can you? After download you can handle the data. You did not tell scenario you are following. So i did not read all that code for now.

Comment: Log details of your problem to Logcat. In particular, in your `catch` block, log the exception to Logcat. Then, examine the Logcat output to see what is going wrong.

Comment: @CommonsWare, hey bro, I've tried so many log.d() and it doesn't show me any information.  The logs just do not show up in the Logcat for some reason.  I've tried breakpoints as well to see what is going on and if I'm receiving the JSON file or not.  Instead in the Debugging panel, I get this message "Variables debug info not available" despite the fact that I've enabled debugging in Build.gradle using 'debuggable true'.  The only thing that seems to work though are Toasts to get me information.

Comment: @blackapps  I know you could download the JSON and make the data available locally, but I thought that by providing the Internet permission in Android Manifest, I should not have to right?  The URL that I've included works and the relative url that I included in my ContactsApi should be correct as I've tried to see if it showed up in Postman, which it does.

Comment: The only thing that could be possibly wrong is that the code may not be reaching the right location.  I should be retrieving the 'data' key from the JSON file to pull the list of contacts.  This line here from my view model should pull up the list of contacts: val dataLoad = loadResponse.data[i].dataList[0], where datalList[0] is the first object in the 'data' list and dataList is the serializedname for 'data' in the data class.  The for loop is there to cycle through the JSON objects until you find one that includes the 'data' key because not all of them do.